# Les neurones qui surchauffent

Tags: expressions, usage

Dans quel contexte est-ce qu’on peut utiliser cette phrase ? Est-ce que c’est au travail quand on est submergé qu’on dit *« oh punaise! j’ai les neurones qui surchauffent »* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premièrement, tu peux retirer « Oh putain » qui est plutôt vulgaire.

> Les neurones qui surchauffent

indique que la tâche à accomplir requiert un effort intellectuel poussé.